# leverage aks-engine to create k8s cluster on mariner-based OS as node

Tags: azure-aks

According to the info in https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#agentpoolprofiles , currently AKS-engine is not support mariner OS. so the questions are:

1. is there any plan and estimation when aks-engine can support mariner os?
2. if there is no plan yet, is it possible to migrate current version AKS-engine to mariner customized? what is suggest solution to do that?

Thanks

I am trying to create K8s on mariner-based OS node by aks-engine

Answer (score 0):

The CBL-Mariner OS image is available for AKS (as preview) since Oct 12 2022 ([source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-infrastructure-blog/announcing-preview-availability-of-the-mariner-aks-container/ba-p/3649154)).

Just use `--os-sku Mariner` option for `az aks create` command to create AKS with such OS image.

**Note**: Don't use `--os-sku CBLMariner` option (still mentioned in MS docs) as this selects an older version of Mariner image which will eventually be deprecated ([source](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/3320#issuecomment-1480128130)).